# Unity URP my shader graph does not function when both input render textures are the same resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader

I created a decal shader for a fog of war effect for my RTS it functions as intended when different resolution the Vision texture is from a top view orthographic camera while the explored texture is an uninitialized camera. the problem is when they are the same resolution the explored texture is not effecting the graph so there is no exploring effect.

when the render textures are the same resolution
[image]
when they are different
[image]
Here is my shader I would love help thank you. the textures in the shader are not the render textures they are test textures but in the actual material they are set to the Propper textures
[image]

I tried rewriting the shader i also created new render textures, and new cameras but nothing seemed to work